# Verifying Back-End Calls from Android Apps

Tags: java, android, maven, google-api-java-client, google-oauth

I am following the [next tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html?m=1) to securized my Rest services.

But I have a problem with the step **Verify Token Fields**, first of all I don't known if my dependencies are the correct:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-gson</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>
```

Secondly when I used the class Checker like in the example, in the call   `Verifier.verify(token)` it returns **false**, it happen because in the class `GoogleIdTokenVerifier` the Set *clientIds* is **empty**. I follow the tutorial step by step, I'm totally lost

Thanks for all.

---

EDIT: This is the code I'm using now, and it seems to be working:

```
public class Checker {

private final String mAudience;
private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private final GoogleIdTokenVerifier mVerifier;
private final JsonFactory mJFactory;
private String mProblem = "Verification failed. (Time-out?)";
private final List<String> mClientIDs;
private List<PublicKey> publicKeys;
private final Clock clock;
NetHttpTransport transport;
private long expirationTimeMilliseconds;

public Checker(String[] clientIDs, String audience) {
    mClientIDs = Arrays.asList(clientIDs);
    mAudience = audience;
    transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    mJFactory = new GsonFactory();
    mVerifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier(transport, mJFactory);
    clock = Clock.SYSTEM;
}

public GoogleIdToken.Payload check(String tokenString) {
    GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = null;

    try {
        GoogleIdToken token = GoogleIdToken.parse(mJFactory, tokenString);
        if (checkSignature(mClientIDs.get(0), token)) {
            GoogleIdToken.Payload tempPayload = token.getPayload();
            if (!tempPayload.getAudience().equals(mAudience))
                mProblem = "Audience mismatch";
            else if (!mClientIDs.contains(tempPayload.getIssuee()))
                mProblem = "Client ID mismatch";
            else
                payload = tempPayload;
        }
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        mProblem = "Security issue: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        mProblem = "Network problem: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mProblem = "Problem: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
    return payload;
}

public String problem() {
    return mProblem;
}

boolean checkSignature(String clientIds, GoogleIdToken idToken)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    JsonWebSignature.Header header = idToken.getHeader();
    String algorithm = header.getAlgorithm();
    if (algorithm.equals("RS256")) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (publicKeys == null
                    || clock.currentTimeMillis() + 300000 > expirationTimeMilliseconds) {
                mVerifier.loadPublicCerts();
                publicKeys = mVerifier.getPublicKeys();
                expirationTimeMilliseconds = mVerifier
                        .getExpirationTimeMilliseconds();
            }
            Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
            for (PublicKey publicKey : publicKeys) {
                signer.initVerify(publicKey);
                signer.update(idToken.getSignedContentBytes());
                if (signer.verify(idToken.getSignatureBytes())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about your dependencies; that’s Maven right?  I’m a Maven moron.

As for your the clientIDs, the code assumes you're going to pass in a list of clientIDs, because you want to make sure you know what client you're going to talk to.  If you don't want to do that, I can see two obvious options:

- just remove the clientIds argument to the constructor, the mClientIDs member variable, and the "if (!mClientIDs.contains()" call in the check() method.
- change the code to skip the check if mClientIDs is null

Comment: Thanks for your help, Tim.

I think I solved the problem of clientIds by using the version of verify that receives the clientIds as a parameter instead of the one that only receives the token:

    verify(Set<String> clientIds, GoogleIdToken idToken) 

But now I have another problem: when the verify method of the __GoogleIdTokenVerifier__ checks the payload it fails, because it evaluates `payload.isValidTime(300)` to _false_.

Finally I managed to solve it with the code I just put in the original question.

Is it correct?

Thanks again!